# how to send string array in soap request to webservice

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, ksoap2

i cant send my request to webservice.

string array not accept and show error to me.

i want to send array string in soap request but show error to me.

my webservice:

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:typens="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="HostIranSmsWebService" targetNamespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService">
<types>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService">
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfstring">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
<xsd:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfint">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
<xsd:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:int[]"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="AccountInfo">
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="numbers" type="typens:ArrayOfstring"/>
<xsd:element name="defaultNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="receiveUrl" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="sent" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element name="received" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element name="credit" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element name="remaining" type="xsd:int"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="send">
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="to" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="msg" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="from" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="time" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
<message name="sendResponse">
<part name="sendResponse" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
<message name="sendToMany">
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="to" type="typens:ArrayOfstring"/>
<part name="msg" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="from" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="time" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
<message name="sendToManyResponse">
<part name="sendToManyResponse" type="typens:ArrayOfint"/>
</message>
<message name="deliveryStatus">
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="recipientId" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
<message name="deliveryStatusResponse">
<part name="deliveryStatusResponse" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
<message name="verifyReceive">
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="ticket" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="verifyReceiveResponse">
<part name="verifyReceiveResponse" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</message>
<message name="accountInfo">
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="accountInfoResponse">
<part name="accountInfoResponse" type="typens:AccountInfo"/>
</message>
<message name="changePassword">
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="newPassword" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="changePasswordResponse">
<part name="changePasswordResponse" type="xsd:void"/>
</message>
<message name="changeTrafficRelay">
<part name="username" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="newURL" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="changeTrafficRelayResponse">
<part name="changeTrafficRelayResponse" type="xsd:void"/>
</message>
<portType name="HostIranSmsWebServicePort">
<operation name="send">
<documentation>Send one SMS.</documentation>
<input message="typens:send"/>
<output message="typens:sendResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="sendToMany">
<documentation>Send one SMS to many.</documentation>
<input message="typens:sendToMany"/>
<output message="typens:sendToManyResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="deliveryStatus">
<documentation>Check SMS delivery status.</documentation>
<input message="typens:deliveryStatus"/>
<output message="typens:deliveryStatusResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="verifyReceive">
<documentation>Verify sms validity when you receive an sms</documentation>
<input message="typens:verifyReceive"/>
<output message="typens:verifyReceiveResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="accountInfo">
<documentation>Get account info.</documentation>
<input message="typens:accountInfo"/>
<output message="typens:accountInfoResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="changePassword">
<documentation>Change account password.</documentation>
<input message="typens:changePassword"/>
<output message="typens:changePasswordResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="changeTrafficRelay">
<documentation>Change traffic relay.</documentation>
<input message="typens:changeTrafficRelay"/>
<output message="typens:changeTrafficRelayResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="HostIranSmsWebServiceBinding" type="typens:HostIranSmsWebServicePort">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="send">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:HostIranSmsWebServiceAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="sendToMany">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:HostIranSmsWebServiceAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="deliveryStatus">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:HostIranSmsWebServiceAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="verifyReceive">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:HostIranSmsWebServiceAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="accountInfo">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:HostIranSmsWebServiceAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="changePassword">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:HostIranSmsWebServiceAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="changeTrafficRelay">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:HostIranSmsWebServiceAction"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="HostIranSmsWebService">
<port name="HostIranSmsWebServicePort" binding="typens:HostIranSmsWebServiceBinding">
<soap:address location="http://sms.hostiran.net/webservice/v1/index.php"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

my code:

```
public String sendToMany(String username,String password,Category to,String msg,String from,Long time){
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    SoapObject soapReq = new SoapObject("urn:HostIranSmsWebService","sendToMany");
    soapReq.addProperty("username",username);
    soapReq.addProperty("password",password);
    soapEnvelope.addMapping("urn:HostIranSmsWebService","to",new Category().getClass());

    soapReq.addProperty("to",to);

    soapReq.addProperty("msg",msg);
    soapReq.addProperty("from",from);
    soapReq.addProperty("time",time);

    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);

    try{

            httpTransport.call("urn:HostIranSmsWebService/sendToMany", soapEnvelope);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}





public class Category extends Vector<String> implements KvmSerializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1166006770093411055L;

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
            return this.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
            return this.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) {
            arg2.name = "string";
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {
            this.add(arg1.toString());
    }
    }
```

my request code:

```
Category to =new Category();
to.add("1111111111");
to.add("2222222222");
to.add("3333333333");
String res = sendToMany("user1", "pass1", to, "hi", "",Long.valueOf(0));
```

error in eclipse:

```
11-14 16:19:51.317: D/msg(681): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: END_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body (position:END_TAG </{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}SOAP-ENV:Fault>@2:199 in java.io.InputStreamReader@44c28540)
```

Can someone help me where is the problem?

Comment: What is the client side code you are using? Basically your request should look like this for match your web service.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand this "As of today SOAP encoding only exists due to some historical reasons non of the standard web service framework supports for SAOP encoding that includes Axis2, Metro and CXF." This was cleanly explained in this article, http://ssagara.blogspot.com/2011/10/soap-encoding-and-axis2.html

But even if you want to use it, Basically your request should look like this for match your web service.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:HostIranSmsWebService" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:sendToMany soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <username xsi:type="xsd:string">?</username>
         <password xsi:type="xsd:string">?</password>
         <to xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfstring" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
         <msg xsi:type="xsd:string">?</msg>
         <from xsi:type="xsd:string">?</from>
         <time xsi:type="xsd:int">?</time>
      </urn:sendToMany>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Read this blog to generate a working client to your project. http://ssagara.blogspot.com/2011/10/soap-encoding-and-axis2.html. As it describes you can use the Axis2's wsdl to code script to generate a working client for this wsdl. Please read the blog carefully and use `wsdl2java.sh -uri service.wsdl -d xmlbeans` command to get a working client.

You can use this tutorial to get further idea. http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jsoap_5/index1.html?page=2

Comment: how to pass this part in my webservice?

sendToMany message:

<part name="to" type="typens:ArrayOfstring"/>

Comment: thanks guys, but still have not my answer...

please help me...

I need this answer... :(

Comment: Why this didn't help you? What you want is to send a request to that web services described in the WSDL ? So you can get  Java client form the above command and you can use it. What has gone wrong with u?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to send an XML request to a SOAP (WCF) endpoint with the following: *(posting my "exact" version to avoid mistranslating)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <MyServiceAction xmlns="http://myservicehost.com/">
            <somestringparameter>aaaaaaaa-0b11-432e-bf14-d8bb5e52e56a</somestringparameter>
            <anotherstring>dont care</anotherstring>
            <thisisanarray arrayType="string[]"><item type="string">OMS.PartnerService</item></thisisanarray>
        </MyServiceAction >
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Corresponding to a (C#) method:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "MyServiceAction")]
bool MyServiceAction(string somestringparameter, string anotherstring, string[] thisisanarray) { ... }
```

In my case, I did not need to specify namespaces beyond the soap envelope (`<soap:Envelop xmlns:soap...>`) and my Action's namespace (`<MyServiceAction xmlns=...>`).  I've seen other examples that declared specific namespaces for the attribute values `string[]` and `string`, but I didn't need them.

But it sounds like from your Eclipse error that your XML was generated incorrectly?  Do you have to manually close an element?